# Resetting Windows' File Security Permissions

Tags: windows, permissions, attributes, icacls, security-groups

I'm trying to find the correct commands to reset each of my hard drives permissions to remove all of the incorrect, outdated groups/usernames that have built up on folders over time and reset the permissions to their defaults.

I've tried running commands like:

```
TAKEOWN /F F:\ /R /D Y
```

It appears to work but doesn't help,

I also tried the likes of:

```
icacls "F:\Example" /reset /T
```

But permissions are deneid because files are read-only for some reason so I need to reset the permissions too but it doesn't appear to work...

```
attrib -H -S F:\*.* /S /D
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to do it in two sweeps.
First, to take ownership -

```
icacls.exe /setowner <username> /t /c /q
```

Second, to reset the ACL's back to the inherited defaults -

```
icacls.exe /reset /t /c /q
```

Comment: The reason your code isn't showing as code is because you need to put a new line between your messages & the part you want shown as code.

Comment: Thanks...the little hints at the side should mention that.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't resolve my problem. files and folders still have permissions setup for other users that aren't the defaults...

Comment: Now that you have owner access, are you able to add/remove accounts to the ACL? Or just select the "Enable inheritance" checkbox?